# json.decorder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value:Line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I have the following code I am trying to deserialize a string I received from a remote connection. I received the data as a byte so i decoded it into a string. However, when I try to deserialize the string (using the code below)

**Code**

[image: code]

**Error** 
[image: results from running the code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your output suggests, the variable `deco` has a value of `test`, which is not valid JSON, so calling `json.loads` with such a value would result in the said error. You should make sure that the sender to the socket sends a valid JSON string instead.

Comment: In other words, you mean i should do as follows: json.loads(json.dumps(deco))

Comment: Yes, if your JSON object is meant to be a simple string literal of `"test"`.